# Update link to stored procedure

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sql-server-express

I have to modify a web site originally written in VS 2010 and is now maintained in VS 2013.  All the linkages to the database (Sql Server) stored procedures were set up in VS 2010.  I have to change a stored procedure to accept an additional parameter which I do in SSMS, however the table adapter in VS 2013 isn't "seeing" the change and the web site code refuses to build.  The code creating, calling the stored procedure via an adapter is:

```
Order_tTableAdapter tblOrderRsr = new Order_tTableAdapter();
tblOrderRsr.eTicket_CreateOrderRecord(userID, eventID, eventDateID, "", tktOrderType, 0, 0, 0,
                                      Email, SIFNAme, SIMI, SILNAme, "", SIAddr1, SIAddr2, SICity,
                                      SIState, SIZip, "", BIFNAme, BIMI, BILNAme, "", BIAddr1, BIAddr2,
                                      BICity, BIState, BIZip, "", "", CustFieldLabel1, CustFieldValue1,
                                      CustFieldLabel2, CustFieldValue2, CustFieldLabel3, CustFieldValue3, 
                                      ref guidRsvID);
```

I assume that I have to somehow update these linkages to the database but cannot find anything in VS 2013 that will allow me to do that.  I have a connection to the database in VS 2013 (Sql Server Express 2012) and can see all the tables and stored procedures, but there isn't any obvious way to update VS 2013 with the changes to the stored procedures (or any changes in the structure for that matter).  How does one make these changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

All the table adapters were created in VS 2010 using the visual designer that is no longer used in VS 2013, BUT (apparently) they did leave the visual designer in VS 2013, you just can't get to it through the menu system.  When the table adapters were created, a file with all that information was created with the name `<YourAppName>.xsd`, this file is located in the `App_Code` folder of the project.  Double click on the file and VS 2013 will open the designer and you can modify the adapters.  Just locate your adapter name and right click on the stored procedure/command located in that adapter and click `Configure` to modify it.